# DWM launching applications incorrectly

Tags: debian, dwm

DWM (6.2) seems to be launching my commands with extra parameters and I'm not sure why. I pretty much have a stock config.h file, the only changes I've made are adding extra commands and keybindings. Two examples: when I launch Dolphin, I expect it to just execute "/usr/bin/dolphin" but instead it appears to execute "/usr/bin/dolphin /home/myuser/st/" which causes Dolphin to launch but in a directory that doesn't exist. When I launch Firefox, there are a bunch of extra tabs with locations like "/usr/bin/terminator","/usr/bin/spotify", etc., basically some of the other commands I have tied to other keybindings. My knowledge on C is pretty limited and I tried looking into the "spawn" function within dwm.c but I don't fully understand it. Here is the relevant part of my config.h file. Thanks all.

```
static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-m", dmenumon, "-fn", dmenufont, "-nb", col_gray1, "-nf", col_gray3, "-sb", col_cyan, "-sf", col_gray4, NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };
static const char *dolphin[] = {"/usr/bin/dolphin"};
static const char *terminator[] = {"/usr/bin/terminator"};
static const char *firefox[] = {"/usr/bin/firefox"};
static const char *spotify[] = {"/usr/bin/spotify"};

/* ##########  Custom Commands : End ########## */

/* ##########  Key Bindings : Start ########## */

static Key keys[] = {
    /* Format = {modifier, key, function, {argument}} */
    { MODKEY,                       XK_p,      spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
    {MODKEY|ShiftMask, XK_e, spawn, {.v = dolphin}},
    {MODKEY|ShiftMask, XK_t, spawn, {.v = terminator}},
    {MODKEY|ShiftMask, XK_i, spawn, {.v = firefox}},
    {MODKEY|ShiftMask, XK_m, spawn, {.v = spotify}},
    { MODKEY,                       XK_b,      togglebar,      {0} },
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! So within the "spawn" function it calls "execvp" (the function that executes commands) which looks like this:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

In this default line:

```
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };
```

It has the the command "st" and arguments "NULL". I modified my own lines to mimic that so:

```
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "/usr/bin/firefox", NULL };
```

And now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't run into this exact error, I did have a similar question regarding *why* the commands needed to end with `NULL`. While the original answer does solve the question of "how to make commands work within the context of dwm", it didn't answer the deeper question of "why is this required".

For those that are also curious, it *is* related to the `execvp` command. Here is the relevant section of the man page:

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of
> pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
> available to the new program. The first argument, by convention,
> should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.
> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp

So it's a restriction imposed by `execvp` and not related to the internal workings of dwm (which is what I originally wanted clarity on).

Since this post came the closest to addressing the deeper question out of many different sources on the internet, I felt that providing more context here made sense for posterity's sake.